# Filling textbox vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in programming with VBA and I need help in filling a textbox with a specific value.

I have in a worksheet multiple columns: Services(A), Head of Service (B) and employee (First Name + Last Name C). Each employee has its own worksheet with its different information, the service is on the column A cell 60 on the worksheet profile.

I have a userform that shows me the employee profile where i have the Service, Head of Service, and the Employee First Name and Last Name. I added a button to the userform to be able to change the head of service whenever needs be.

The problem is when I do it, it only changes the head of service for the current profile i am visiting. I want to make the change for all employees that are in the same service.

The code I'm using is this:

```
'''
Private Sub Valider_Click()

If Me.Combox_Nv_Resp = "" Then

    MsgBox ("choisissez un nouveau Responsable")

Else

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Personne)
    fin_col_Resp_Serv = ws.Cells(60, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column
    fin_liste = ws_Liste_Pers.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Cells(60, fin_col_Resp_Serv) = Me.Combox_Nv_Resp.Value
    UF_Profil_Edit1.TextBox_Resp_Service = Combox_Nv_Resp.Value

    Unload Me

End If

End Sub

'''
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add some links to screenshots of what your worksheet(s) look like? I'm a little confused on how the data is laid out. What I'm initially thinking is that you would loop through all worksheets (`For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets`), then check to see if the Service matches the one that was just changed, and if so, update the Head of Service as well.